# How Output of this program comes out to be this

Tags: c, linux

Its C program which is running x86_64 machine ,Wanted to know how output is coming like this way

```
main()
 {
 int  *mess;
mess=malloc(1);
mess[0]=1;
//mess[1]=2; 
printf("%d",mess);
}
```

Now output here is 6295568

How is it??

Comment: mess != mess[0] you display a part of address of mess

Comment: When you compile this program under gcc you will get warning. use printf("%d",*mess);

Comment: You are invoking undefined behaviour by allocating one byte and then writing four bytes.  You are then printing the address using an `int` format, which is more undefined behaviour.  On a 64-bit machine, the size of an address is not the same as the size of an `int` which the `%d` expects.  You should also use an explicit return type of `int` on `main()` (C99 requires that).  It is best to end your outputs with a newline, too.  Compile your code with maximal warnings and clean up the warnings the compiler generates.  Remember: it knows more about C than you (or I) do.

Answer (score 6):

You're printing the address where your int is stored. You need

```
printf("%d",*mess);
```

to print its value.

You are also allocating too little space for your int, you should do:

```
int *mess = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

instead of

```
int *mess = malloc(1);
```

Comment: He also needs to allocate enough space to hold an integer: malloc(sizeof(int))

Comment: main()
{
int  *mess;
mess=malloc(1);
mess[0]=1;
mess[1]=2;
printf("%d",mess[0]);
printf("\n%d",*mess);
}
for this piece of code I am getting 1 1??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: yes, as expected...?

Comment: How is it ,malloc(sizof(int); also shows same O/P

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: it works because you're lucky that there's padding on most platforms. You should consider reading a book/tutorial about C memory management, this is very basic stuff that has been explained plenty of times elsewhere.

Comment: @houbysoft could you please tell me how I point to mess buffer here since *mess also pointing to first member of mem, I wanted to get the complete mess buffer